# typescript extending interface doesn't allow to overwrite property

Tags: typescript, typing

Typescript apparently doesn't allow me to overwrite a property being not required.
I have a couple of interfaces:

```
interface IField {

  label:                string;
  model:                string;
  placeholder?:         string;
  addon?:               string;
  showOn?:              IDictionary <string | number>;
  maxlength?:           number;

}
interface ICheckboxField extends IField {

  model?:               string;
  type:                 'checkbox';
  default?:             string;
  options:              IOption[];
  validation?:    {
    required?:          string;
  };
}
```

So in the ICheckboxField I set the model property to be not required.
All other fields that extend IField do need to have a required model.

Is this a restriction in Typescript or is there a solution other then not extending the interface and just adding the properties specifically for the interface?

Comment: You cannot change the type or modifiers of existing properties when extending (or merging)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do is put the shared properties of `IField` and `ICheckboxField` in a shared interface:

```
interface IBase {
    label: string;
    placeholder?: string;
    addon?: string;
    showOn?: IDictionary;
    maxlength?: number;
}

interface IField extends IBase {
    model: string;
}

interface ICheckboxField extends IBase {
    model?: string;
    type: 'checkbox';
    default?: string;
    options: IOption[];
    validation?: {
        required?: string;
    };
}
```

Another option is to separate `IField` into two interfaces:

```
interface IField {
    label: string;
    placeholder?: string;
    addon?: string;
    showOn?: IDictionary;
    maxlength?: number;
}

interface IFieldOptionalModel extends IField {
    model?: string;
}

interface IFieldMandatoryModel extends IField {
    model: string;
}

interface ICheckboxField extends IFieldOptionalModel {
    type: 'checkbox';
    default?: string;
    options: IOption[];
    validation?: {
        required?: string;
    };
}
```

Comment: I look your second suggestion with having an optional and mandatory interface. That might be actually reused in the future so I will go with that.

Answer (score 0):

You trying to override a strict type (`IField`) where the property is mandatory with a looser type (`ICheckboxField`) where it's made mandatory.

The compiler frowns on that, but the opposite is possible:

```
interface Loose {
  label:string;
  model?:string;
}

interface Strict extends Loose {
  model:string;
}

var a:Loose = {
  label:"bar",
}

var b:Strict = {
  label: "baz",
  model: "me"
}
```

So you could add another interface on top of both, where the model field is defined as optional and then redefine it as mandatory in `IField`.

Another option could be using `keyof` and the Lookup Types [added in TypeScript 2.1](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I do think the other answer will work a bit better for me. Cheers